# Handle iOS Memory Warning with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, memory

I am really surprised no one has asked this yet: how do I handle iOS memory warnings with PhoneGap?

Specifically, **how do I call one of my JS functions when the iOS native application receives a memory warning**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a plugin that calls any js function you want, CDVPlugin already have an overridable onMemoryWarning method.

```
- (void)onMemoryWarning
{
    NSString * javascriptString = @"yourJSFunctionToManageMemoryWarnings();";
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
}
```